# Editing voronoi class to return polygon points in python

Tags: python, graph, voronoi

Would anyone with Python experience be able to take a look at this for me?

I'm using this code:

https://bitbucket.org/mozman/geoalg/src/5bbd46fa2270/geoalg/voronoi.py

to perform voronoi tesselation on a group of points.

It works, but the problem is that the code only provides a list of all the vertices used to create the polygons, and which pairs must be joined together. It doesn't provide any information as to what points are used to make up each polygon, which I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`context.triangles` says in which Delaunay triangles input point participate. Each triangle is related to a Voronoi vertex. Triangles and vertices are stored parallel in `triangles` and `vertices` arrays.

To find Voronoi cell for a given point `p`, it is needed to find all vertices (triangles) in which input point is used. And than find order how these vertices are connected by `edges` array.

Here is a simple (not quite tested) code to do that:

```
from voronoi import voronoi
import random
from collections import defaultdict

num_points = 50
points = [(random.uniform(0,10), random.uniform(0,10)) for i in xrange(num_points)]
c = voronoi(points)

# For each point find triangles (vertices) of a cell
point_in_triangles = defaultdict(set)
for t_ind, ps in enumerate(c.triangles):
    for p in ps:
        point_in_triangles[p].add(t_ind)

# Vertex connectivity graph
vertex_graph = defaultdict(set)
for e_ind, (_, r, l) in enumerate(c.edges):
    vertex_graph[r].add(l)
    vertex_graph[l].add(r)

def cell(point):
    if point not in point_in_triangles:
        return None
    vertices = set(point_in_triangles[point]) # copy
    v_cell = [vertices.pop()]
    vertices.add(-1)  # Simulate infinity :-)
    while vertices:
        neighbours = vertex_graph[v_cell[-1]] & vertices
        if not neighbours:
            break
        v_cell.append(neighbours.pop())
        vertices.discard(v_cell[-1])
    return v_cell

for p in xrange(num_points):
    print p, cell(p)
```

Comment: That's amazing, thanks! It seems to work perfectly too. I had one small follow up question, the results that cell(p) returns, the list of numbers, are those the index values for the vertices? They all return values but it's tricky to test.

Comment: Ah, no, it's alright. My results were being a bit confused by the infinity values. But really, thanks again, I've been stuck on this for ages and this is so helpful.

Comment: Great stuff, works well. I noticed that both Boost's voronoi and this one produce outliers. Not at infinity, but still very far away from the original point set. I can't figure out why.

Comment: @Bram Probably to describe separation lines between points. If point in infinity is used, than that segment (ray) has to be defined by direction. It is easier to define it in 'standard way' (by two points) and it is always easy to check far away point.